# Flip two images on click

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am coding a small two column accordion list which elements have an arrow image on the right side. When I click a list item, the arrow flips up and when I click on it again, it flips down (it toggles) , but if I click on it and the arrow goes up, and then click on another item, the previous arrow stays pointing up. How can I make them both toggle at the same time?

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ujbLxxt7/).

Here is some code:

```
$('#accordCont ul > li').click(function() {
    $(this).find('img:last-child').toggleClass('flipped');
    $(this).find('img:last-child').next().toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please find the solution here:

This allows for multiple `ul's`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#accordCont ul > li div').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }).hide();

        $('#accordCont ul > li').click(function() {
            var selfClick = $(this).find('div:first').is(':visible');
            if (!selfClick) {
                $(this).parent().find('> li div:visible').slideToggle();
            }

            $(this)
                .find('div:first')
                .stop(true, true)
                .slideToggle();
        });

        $('#accordCont ul > li').click(function() {
            var img = $(this).find('img:last-child')
            img.toggleClass('flipped');
            img.next().toggleClass('flipped');
            $("img.flipArrow").not(img).removeClass("flipped");
        });
    });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ujbLxxt7/2/)

Comment: My pleasure @Sqnkov :)